# Average of all values in multiple Stata variables

Tags: stata, data-analysis

I have 2 variables, and I want a summary table with the average (a single number) of all non-missing values across both columns (the variables record the same thing, but in the raw data I imported they have been recorded as separate variables), without regard to which column something is in.

More concretely, if I have something like

```
Var1          Var2
  1            .
  12           5
  3            2
  4.5          .
  .            2
```

I want to get the average of all non-missing values in both Var1 and Var2, i.e. `(1+12+3+4.5+5+2+2)/7`

One idea I had was to create a single variable, say `Var3`, where I "append" Var1 and Var2, i.e. generate a variable

```
Var3 
1 
12 
3 
4.5 
. 
. 
5 
2 
. 
2
```

and just use the table I get from `summarize Var3`, but there seems to be no easy way to "append" the variables. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that.

```
. list 

     +-------------+
     | var1   var2 |
     |-------------|
  1. |    1      . |
  2. |   12      5 |
  3. |    3      2 |
  4. |  4.5      . |
  5. |    .      2 |
     +-------------+

. preserve

. stack var1 var2, into(var)
Warning:  data in memory will be lost.
         Press any key to continue, Ctrl-Break to abort.

. su var

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         var |          7    4.214286    3.717718          1         12

. l

     +--------------+
     | _stack   var |
     |--------------|
  1. |      1     1 |
  2. |      1    12 |
  3. |      1     3 |
  4. |      1   4.5 |
  5. |      1     . |
     |--------------|
  6. |      2     . |
  7. |      2     5 |
  8. |      2     2 |
  9. |      2     . |
 10. |      2     2 |
     +--------------+

. restore

. l

     +-------------+
     | var1   var2 |
     |-------------|
  1. |    1      . |
  2. |   12      5 |
  3. |    3      2 |
  4. |  4.5      . |
  5. |    .      2 |
     +-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the data, you could use `summarize` to get the average of the two variables.

```
  clear
input Var1          Var2
  1            .
  12           5
  3            2
  4.5          .
  .            2
end

list
/*   +-------------+
     | Var1   Var2 |
     |-------------|
  1. |    1      . |
  2. |   12      5 |
  3. |    3      2 |
  4. |  4.5      . |
  5. |    .      2 |
     +-------------+ */

sum Var1 
local sum_v1 = r(sum)
local N_v1   = r(N)

sum Var2 
local sum_v2 = r(sum)
local N_v2   = r(N)

local average_v1_v2 = (`sum_v1' + `sum_v2') / (`N_v1' + `N_v2')

di `average_v1_v2'
*4.2142857
```